# Get sql entires based on value in same table

Tags: database

So i have a database with a number of AccountId's and GameId's. I want to get all entries where a where a specified AccountId is used, furthermore i only want them if the table contains a value pair where a specified accountID (different one) has the same GameId as for one of the entries gotten.

An example of this could be

| AccountId | GameID |
| --- | --- |
| asd | 123 |
| zxc | 123 |
| zxc | 789 |

In this example the AccountId zxc would be the first specified AccountId while asd would be the seccond.
In this case i only want the the following returned

| AccountId | GameID |
| --- | --- |
| zxc | 123 |

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.AccountId, t1.GameId
from TableName t1
    inner join TableName t2 on
        t1.GameId = t2.GameId
where t1.AccountId = 'Accountid1' AND t2.AccountId = 'AccountId2'
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.